# Inserting page numbers to handout and attaching layout page number to table of contents in beamer layout

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, beamerarticle, layout

I have a huge beamer presentation and decided to use the handout beamer documentclass in which I use 2 frames on one page to produce a book like version of  the presentation. 
Since it's such a big presentation, I decided not to make use of the frame numbers. Instead I would like to put the actual page number at the bottom of a 2 on 1 page. I kind of managed this with:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgfsys@endpicture{%
    \makebox[\pgfphysicalwidth]{\the\numexpr\value{page}/2\relax}%
}
```

This number is really at the bottom of the layout page and somehow doesn't start with page no. 1 but page no. 2. So my questions are as follows:

1. How will I manage to get a page numbering starting with one on the first page?
2. Is it possible to raise this number by half a cm?
3. Furthermore I would like to attach this layout page number to my table of contents for my sections and subsection? e.g. a section starts on frame 4 so I want page 2 displayed on ToC. I'm not sure if this is even possible in beamer.

I am trying to avoid the frame numbers! 
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please include a minimal working example for your question; it makes it much easier to help you, and often will solve your problem by itself.

Comment: Note that the TOC uses \thepage (which can be redefined to be pretty much anything).